# What is the purpose of hiding EmailAuthProvider for firebase_auth?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

What is the purpose of the "hide" I see in almost all the example imports like the one below?

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'        
    hide EmailAuthProvider, PhoneAuthProvider;           // new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `hide` is used to only partially import names from the referenced library. In your case, you import all names except for the ones `EmailAuthProvider` and `PhoneAuthProvider`.

This can be useful when you import two libraries that contain the same name. Then you can hide one to make it clear which one to use.

For context, take a look at the [dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#importing-only-part-of-a-library).

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense to me now.  The import I show above was out of context.  The example I was working from had both firebase_auth and firebase_ui_auth imports.  So the hide is to make sure that we are getting the providers from firebase_ui_auth.  Thank you very much.  I tried to upvote your answer, but I guess I am too new :-(